# Possessive form of in-law

Tags: possessives

I need a bit of help with this.

> She is a photographer but that camera is her **brother's-in-law**

or:

> She is a photographer but that camera is her **brother-in-law's**

I am aware that I could change the construction to make things easier, like:

> She is a photographer but that camera belongs to her brother-in-law

However, I would really like to find out what's the correct way to write the sentence.

Comment: [*brother-in-law*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=brother-in-law) is considered one word, so you would use "brother-in-law's". The dashes indicate this.

Comment: @J.R. I don't think you should edit in the dashes since that partly explains the answer.

Comment: user3169 explains it.  It might make it easier to see if we use a different example: **"That chair is the King of Spain's"** - not **"the King's of Spain"**!

Comment: @user3169 - That's a valid point. Feel free to edit them back out.

Answer (score 2):

The hyphenation in the word

> brother-in-law

makes it a [compound noun](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4797/plural-form-of-brother-in-law-when-a-possesive-case-is-involved), in which case the possessive is

> brother-in-law's  *( the plural possessive is brothers-in-law's )*
>   mother-in-law's
>   Commander-in-Chief's

even if the hyphens are not explicit, if a group of words are being treated as a compound noun, the possessive is at the end

> the President of the United States' plane

[image: here]

> the Queen of England's crown

[image: here]

> the Greatest of All Time's smile

[image: here]

> the hottest model in the world's hair

[image]

Comment: Good examples! But I can understand how this might be confusing for a learner, particularly since the plural form is _brothers-in-law_.