# How to say it about my brother in law guitar?

Tags: nouns, possessives

The most precious thing for me was ....
a) my brother-in-law guitar
b) my brother’s-in-law guitar
c) my brother-in-law’s guitar
d) my brother’-in-law guitar
e) my brother’s-in-law’s guitar

Comment: Related: [Plural form of “brother-in-law” when a possessive case is involved](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4797/)

Answer (score -2):

Well, you have two options:

- The guitar of my brother-in-law
- My brother-in-law's guitar